# No way to get website addon working on OpenERP windows installation

Tags: windows, python-2.7, web, odoo

i've managed until now any kind of addons and customizations for OpenERP on my windows installation.
I know it's not the best environment for OpeneERP but it's working for me.
Anyway i still get with this last addon(website) the error:
"cannot import module name request"

I've installed with easy-install the request module on my python 2.7 installation and also tried to copy the compiled requests module under addons but no success.

Any idea ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No response.Actually i get it worked only under ubuntu!